# Laravel API Pagination ErrorException

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I'm working on simple API in Laravel 5 and i want to make pagination because of lot of data in database.

This is method which is called on GET request for route api/v1/words

```
public function index()
    {
        //$words = Word::all();
        $limit = Input::get('limit') ?: 3;
        $words = Word::paginate($limit);
        //dd(get_class_methods($words));
        return $this->respondWithPagination($words);
    }
                     .
                     .  
                     .

    public function respondWithPagination($words)
    {
        return $this->respond([
            'words' => $this->wordTransformer->transformCollection($words->all()),
            'paginator' => [
                'totalCount' => $words->getTotal(),
                'totalPages' => ceil($words->getTotal() / $words->getPerPage()),
                'currentPage' => $words->getCurrentPage(),
                'limit' => $words->getPerPage(),
                'previousPageUrl' => $words->previousPageUrl(),
                'nextPageUrl' => $words->nextPageUrl()
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

But my log gives me this error:

```
[2015-04-17 09:50:28] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection' does not have a method 'getTotal'' in /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php:463
    Stack trace:
    #0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'call_user_func_...', '/home/vagrant/C...', 463, Array)
    #1 /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php(463): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #2 /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus2/app/Http/Controllers/WordController.php(90): Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator->__call('getTotal', Array)
    #3 /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus2/app/Http/Controllers/WordController.php(90): Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator->getTotal()
    #4 /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus2/app/Http/Controllers/WordController.php(43): App\Http\Controllers\WordController->respondWithPagination(Object(Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator))
    #5 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\WordController->index()
    #6 /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(246): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$words` is an `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`  object (see documentation [here](http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html)).

You have called a method which doesn't belong

- neither to the `Paginator` class
- nor to its underlying `Collection` accessed through dynamic call (see also documentation [here](http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html)).

Explore/study *thoroughly* the documentations to know the correct spelling of the methods you need.

---

Hints:

- `count()`: Get the number of items for the (`Paginator`) current page ([reference](http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html#method_count)).
- `count()`: Count the number of items in the (underlying) `Collection` ([reference](http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_count)).

Comment: Thanks, well now i see that i was looking Laravel 4.1 documentation instead Laravel 5. Also `dd(get_class_methods($words));` show that there is no getTotal() method